# Insert set of images in latex

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have a processus that I would represent it by a set of images like the below image. How can do this using the subfigure package?

[image]

Comment: Should the images be numbered? That is, should `title1`, `title2`, ... be referenceable using (say) (a), (b), ...?

Comment: @Werner, In the 4th layers, I would give a title for each image.

Comment: @Werner, I think i found the solution. I will share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This arrangement doesn't require anything special. Here's such an arrangement inside a `figure` that doesn't use any sub-figure package. Elements are not referenceable though (that can be changed, if needed):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\newcommand{\subfigANDtitle}[2][.2\linewidth]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}} #2 \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}

  This is a long title A.

  \medskip

  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}

  This is a long title B.

  \medskip

  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}

  This is a long title C.

  \medskip

  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title A} \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title B} \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title C} \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title D}

  \medskip

  \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title A} \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title B}
  \hfill\mbox{}

  \medskip

  \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title C} \hfill
  \subfigANDtitle{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image} \\ title D}
  \hfill\mbox{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would increase the dimension of images of the layer 5th and 6th. I try to put .4 instead of 0.2 but images becomes not well aligned

Comment: @phdstudent: Ahhh, yes. I defined `\subfigANDtitle[<width>]{<stuff>}` to take an optional `<width>` argument. The default is `.2\linewidth`. So, perhaps use `\subfigANDtitle[.4\linewidth]{<stuff>}`.